# ADD failed : No such file/Directory while building docker image

Tags: docker

I have below Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p /test/code/
RUN mkdir -p /test/logs/
RUN mkdir -p /test/configs/

ADD test.py /test/code/
ADD test_output.txt /test/code/
ADD test_input.txt /test/configs/
ADD logfile.log /test/logs/


CMD [ "python3", "/test/code/test.py" ]
```

My directory structure is:

```
/home/<username>/test/
                 |-> code/Dockerfile, test_output.txt, test.py
                 |-> logs/logfile.log
                 |-> configs/test_input.txt
```

when I am building the docker image using below command:

```
sudo docker build -t myimage .
```

It shows below error:

```
Step 7/9 : ADD test_input.txt /test/configs/
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder562406652/test_input.txt: no such file or directory
```

Why it shows this error when I have the directory and my file is also present.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This doesn't work because `test_input.txt` is not in the [docker build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage).

When you execute the command `sudo docker build -t myimage .` the last '.' indicates the build context. What docker does is that it uploads the context to the docker deamon to build the image. In your case the context does not contain `test_input.txt`, thus it is not uploaded and docker can't find the file/

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Inside test directory run the command `sudo docker build -t myimage -f code/Dockerfile .`. In this case the context includes all the test directory. Then modify the Dockerfile to account for this change:

---

```
FROM python:3
...    
ADD code/test.py /test/code/
ADD code/test_output.txt /test/code/
ADD config/test_input.txt /test/configs/
ADD logs/logfile.log /test/logs/
```

2. The second option is to simply move the Dockerfile to the test folder and modify it as above. In that case the command `sudo docker build -t myimage .` should work.

Comment: For your first option, it gives error while building that `it requires exactly 1 argument`. For the second option, the image is successfully build but when I run its container it says `python3: can't open file '/test/code/test.py': [Errno 20] Not a directory`

Comment: @AnnaCarolina For the first option,  the `.` which is the argument to the build command that docker is complaining about was missing. Fixed that. As for the second error, try to  browse the container, by running `sudo docker run -it myimage bash` and go to `/test/code` and make sure test/py is not there.

Answer (score 8):

Also make sure to not add in the `.dockerignore file` a file or folder that is needed during the image building process.

Comment: If you get the error though file exists then exactly as @soscier said make sure the file you added is not in .dockerignore

Answer (score 0):

Because test_input.txt is in another directory,either put this file in place where dockerfile is there similar to test_output.txt or give full path in ADD command

```
ADD ../configs/test_input.txt /test/configs/
```

Even for logfile.log this u will get error , so change to

```
ADD ../logs/logfile.log /test/logs/
```

Comment: By full path you mean `/home/<username>/test/configs/test_input.txt` & same for log file.

Comment: yes, or just go one folder back with ../folder_name

Comment: Yes I have given the full path but it still shows the error.