# Can't build php docker image

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I got this error when building docker php image

> Step 13/25 : ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
>
> ERROR: Service 'phpt3' failed to build: ADD failed: stat
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder310748204/php.ini: no
> such file or directory

Below is the docker file:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# install the PHP extensions we need
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends msmtp mailutils vim curl debconf subversion git apt-transport-https apt-utils \
    build-essential locales acl mailutils wget nodejs \
    gnupg gnupg1 gnupg2 \
    zlib1g-dev zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ \
    sudo

# Install GD
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ 
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# MYSQLI 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

# Install ext-zip
RUN apt-get install -y unzip libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql json calendar intl

ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY additionnal.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

COPY php-fpm-pool.conf  /usr/local/etc/php/pool.d/www.conf

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version

# set up sendmail config, see http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssmtp.conf for options
RUN echo "hostname=localhost.localdomain" > /etc/msmtp/msmtp.conf
RUN echo "mailhub=maildevt3" >> /etc/msmtp/msmtp.conf
# The above 'maildevt3' is the name you used for the link command
# in your docker-compose file or docker link command.
# Docker automatically adds that name in the hosts file
# of the container you're linking MailDev to.

# Set up php sendmail config
RUN echo "sendmail_path=sendmail -i -t" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-sendmail.ini

# Fully qualified domain name configuration for sendmail on localhost.
# Without this sendmail will not work.
# This must match the value for 'hostname' field that you set in ssmtp.conf.
RUN echo "localhost localhost.localdomain" >> /etc/hosts 

WORKDIR /var/www/

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Can anyone help me to overcome this bug.

I'm doing this tutorial
https://passions.miary.dev/2019/08/30/docker-maildev-fr/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the image installer does not have the rights to write to the installation directory.

-> How to fix:

1. [ADD failed : No such file/Directory while building docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977699/add-failed-no-such-file-directory-while-building-docker-image)
2. If that doesn't work: test if the folder, which is shown in the error exists.
3. Give enough permissions to the directory with `chmod` -> https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/chmod/

Comment: As this OP's question is a duplicate you should not provide an answer linking to the duplicate. You should vote to close as a duplicate of the question. Providing links to solutions is not an answer. Additionally, while these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry, It's not the same thing. I tried to do wht he said but i have got the same error